# Counting the number of undirected simple and connected graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to count the number of undirected simple and connected graphs with $2k$ different vertex so there is a an one and only edge that if will remove it, the graph will be build of two disconnected graphs $G_1,G_2$ so they are both complete graphs?

How can I approach this issue?

Comment: If $G_1$ has $m$ vertices and $G_2$ has $n$ vertices, both complete, then there are $mn$ ways to add a single edge to connect them distinctly if the vertices are distinct.

Comment: @LaarsHelenius Thank you. how does it help?

Comment: It means that there are $mn$ graphs that have a single edge connecting two cliques of order $m$ and $n$. When you remove that single edge you get two disconnected cliques.